# Login logs in Windows 10

Tags: shell, logging, authentication

The case is that I need to track my office hours so why not to use my windows login time? Is there any chance that windows hold that information? Should I proceed with a custom script to track my login time?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem using [this guide](https://www.maketecheasier.com/see-pc-startup-and-shutdown-history-in-windows/). 
Long story short,

- press`windows + R` enter `eventvwr.msc`
- navigate to System
- check the provided logs

Hope this helps as it helped me :)